# Remove Attribute From Input Checkbox in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove the input type checkbox checked attribute on click of id="chk1" checkbox.

```
<div class="index1" id="test1">
    <h2>testing1</h2>
    <div class="str">
        <ul>
            <li class="nvc1">
                <input type="checkbox" value="in1" id="chk2" checked="checked" />
                <div class="checkbox-select">str1</div>
                <div class="checkbox-deselect">str2</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="index2" id="test2">
    <h2>testing2</h2>
    <div class="string">
        <ul>
            <li class="nv1">
                <input type="checkbox" value="in1" id="chk1" />
                <div class="checkbox-select">lblstr1</div>
                <div class="checkbox-deselect">lblstr2</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any reference for this/

Thanks,
ShailShin

Comment: your JS snippet please

Answer (score 5):

I suggest this:

```
$("#chk1").on("change", function(){
    $("#chk2").prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Change `#chk2` checked status depend on `#chk1`.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/axw75/9/)

Comment: As per the question, this would be the answer. Voted.

Answer (score 2):

In JQuery you can use:

```
jQuery('#chk1').click(function()
{
    jQuery('#chk1').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

But does it makes sense? :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Jquery you can do this easily

http://jsfiddle.net/gcS4T/

```
$('#chk1').click(function () {
    $('#chk2').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

id should be unique and to remove the 'checked' attribute you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function()({
   $('#chk1').click(function(){
      $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);

   //or 
  // $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#chk1").removeAttr('checked').checkboxradio('refresh');
```

Hope this helps....